# Django e commerce работа с моделями

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование, backend, django-model

У меня возникает тупик с работай моделей. Я создаю интернет магазин. Пример у меня есть модель продукта и к ней присоединена модель предмет продукта связью m2m. Другой пример я продаю ключи от Windows это продукт, а сам код это отдельная модель title и key они связаны m2m связью. Также есть profile пользователя, где есть купленные продукты. То есть мне надо убрать связь между продуктом и установить её с profile. Как это сделать если человек покупает 4 ключа, получается надо достать 4 предмета продукта то есть ключ и присоединить к профилю. Если надо пенять модели, то покажите пожалуйста код

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Название', max_length=250)
    item = models.ManyToManyField('ItemProduct',blank=True,verbose_name='Предмет продукта')
class ItemProduct(model.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Название', max_length=250)
    item = models.TextField('Продукт')
class Profile(models.Model):
""" Профиль пользователя """
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Пользователь")
    orders = models.ManyToManyField(ItemProduct, blank=True, verbose_name='Покупки')
```

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Привел минимальный пример кода, чтобы понять проблему